# Subject & Retry operation not working as expected after OnError

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, system.reactive

After calls "OnError", it looks like a deadlock occurs.
Even if I specify a Scheduler.Default the result is worse, causing a thread spinning to pull.

I picked up this example in http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html

```
var result = source
    .Retry()
    .Finally(() =>
        Console.WriteLine("Finally")
    );

result.Subscribe(
        Console.WriteLine,
        Console.WriteLine,
        () => Console.WriteLine("Completed")
    );

source.OnNext(1);
source.OnNext(2);
source.OnNext(3);
source.OnError(new Exception("Fail"));
source.OnNext(4);

Console.ReadKey();
```

I'm currently using **.NET 4** and **Reactive Extensions - Main Library 2.2.4**

Comment: You may have received down votes for the improper use of a Subject? I am not sure. Either way, the code you've posted gives a very explicit example of the problem you're having, and I'm glad you took the time to write it. I would hope, however, that your production ready code looks nothing like this when using Rx. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Subject` remembers if it has received an `OnError` or an `OnCompleted`. If so, any new subscribers will receive the same `OnError` or `OnCompleted` event as soon as they subscribe. Since `Retry` will indefinitely re-subscribe when it knows the underlying observable has erred or completed, you will infinitely resubscribe to an erred source.

To be more specific, after you've `OnError`'d the subject in your example, all other `OnNext` and `OnCompleted` events (and OnError, for that matter) are ignored, and the subject will only ever send the `OnError` event to all existing and any new subscribers. Your `Retry` is therefore just an infinite loop of error events (which `Retry` does not send downstream). In essence, `Retry` is doing exactly as it is designed to do.

It is worth noting that `Retry` has an overload which takes a number. This number determines the number of times to retry before giving up and forwarding on the error.

```
subject.Retry(10).Subscribe();
```

Comment: Is there any way to not "compromise" my subject?

Comment: Don't use a subject. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I read something about 'dont use a subject', but if I have a business logic using many sources and targets of events, which leads to an increased encapsulation, and I need handle next, error and completed. Why wouldn't a good idea to use it?

Comment: It may very well be. Or, you may just want to use Merge and Publish. Either way, if an error occurs, each subscriber will need to Resubscribe, unless the error never reaches the subscribers.